# Python generic functions dispatching

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming, python-decorators, functools

Is there are any way to dispatch a function which arguments may be:

- single lambda-function (i.e. `func(lambda x: x)`)
- kwargs (i.e. `func(a='some sting', b='some other string')`)

As I see it, `singledispatch` decorator from `functools` only supports dispatching on the first argument, which in my case won't work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not missing anything. single dispatch won't solve your problem

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/multipledispatch

can help you with positional arguments but not keywords :(